# Div: full header without horizontal scrolling (neither with arrow keys)

Tags: html, css, scroll, width

Already a long time ago I started with a new homepage project. I've learnt to build up a homepage on my own, so I'm still in the learning process. Therefore, it might be possible, that I've chosen sometimes not the best way to implement something.

I'd like to have a full width header (and footer) on my webpage. For this reason I created some div tags like this one below:

```css
.header_container_overall-1 {
 height: 90px;
 width: 1000px;
 padding-left: 1000px;
 margin-left: -1000px;
 padding-right: 1000px;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

The problem now is, that a browser (or a mobile device) shows a horizontal scroll bar. I read in a post, that I could use "overflow-x: hidden;". I applied this snippet of code into the "body" class of my css-file. The horizontal scroll bar disappeared, but you can still scroll to the right using the arrow keys on your keyboard.
Unfortunately, I kept programming my website knowing this bug (I thought, that I will fix this later, but I think, this was not the best idea). However, I now came back to this bug and tried to fix it. I found several threads, in which the same problem occured:

*kennykee.com/118/div-100-width-without-horizontal-scroll-bar/*

*stackoverflow.com/questions/18274386/div-overflow-is-hidden-but-still-can-scroll-using-keyboard-right-arrow-key*

Then, I tried the following steps:

- adding the "overflow-x: hidden;" to several classes (especially the header and footer classes) with the aim to prevent horizontal scrolling. I tried several options and in the end, I got a website, where the header and footer got clipped at the body (for example I got a width of 1000px instead of a full width).
- when I tried to use "position: relative;" or "position: fixed;" in different classes, I ended up, that the main page (which is now centered because of margin-left and margin-right set to "auto") was set to the left.

I hope, you understand what I mean. It's hard to describe, even more with my bad English ;-). And as you can see, I sometimes tried stuff without even knowing, what I'm doing. It was more and more "try and error" and I came now to the desicion, that I'm at the end of my html and css knowledge to fix this problem. Maybe you can see the problem right now or maybe you have an idea, what I could try to do.

The website with the described error is available on:
http://www.airlink.ch

The css file is available too:
http://www.airlink.ch/stylesheets/layout.css

If you need any further information, please let me know. And sorry for this long explanation.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I did not read the post much further than your CSS. I am sorry but you should not be using hacks like padding 1000 PX and margin 1000px. If you want a full width div, set the HTML and body elements to width: 100%. Then add width 100% to your header/footer div. Make sure to add the meta viewport tag for width = device width. You should do a quick google for some resources regarding device width and responsive design in general.

Hope you can get what you want working!